# Google API places intent PlaceAutoComplete crashing after launch

Tags: android, google-places-api

After searching a lot of solutions at stackoverflow none of the posts help me.
I change my fingerprint,i wrote in the manifest:

```
  <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="@string/google_api_key1" />
```

I add this code to my fragment:

```
@Override
public void showEditAddress() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.e(TAG, "Show error: " + e.toString());
    }

}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getContext(), data);
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getContext(), data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.e(TAG, "Error Places: " + status.toString());

            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }
```

But still after its display the activity of google its crush, i am working on it couple of days and nothing works :(

Here what i get from the console:

```
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
teame.co.il.team_e V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 7599
teame.co.il.team_e V/FA: Connecting to remote service
teame.co.il.team_e V/FA: Activity paused, time: 431544392
teame.co.il.team_e D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=7599, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MyProfileActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4880950556395788363}]
teame.co.il.team_e V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
teame.co.il.team_e D/FA: Connected to remote service
teame.co.il.team_e V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
teame.co.il.team_e D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=109
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 834) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 834) or=1
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,2220] newFrame=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 508726705152} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
teame.co.il.team_e D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 508726705152}
teame.co.il.team_e V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@d2f12df nm : teame.co.il.team_e ic=null
teame.co.il.team_e I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
teame.co.il.team_e D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=109
teame.co.il.team_e E/MyProfileFragment: Error Places: Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}   //The Error from the log
teame.co.il.team_e V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 431544700
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 126) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 126) or=1
teame.co.il.team_e D/ViewRootImpl@d7aa753[MyProfileActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,2220] newFrame=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 508726705152} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
teame.co.il.team_e D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
teame.co.il.team_e V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Image of the restiction ay my google api console:

[image]

Comment: Please add crash logs if there are any, and general logs from few seconds around your test run if that's possible. Also - do you finally get a call to `onActivityResult`? What's the `resultCode`? Anything in the `data` intent?

Comment: i edit my post...

Comment: first of all: it is not crashing. Second: `ERROR` sadly is an "error without further details" based on the documention. Have you tried it with an API key that has no restrictions?

Comment: Are you doing anything else Firebase related in the bg? Also - have you tried your credentials with the JS API?

Comment: WarrenFaith - there arent any restriction i did triple check Vaiden - i using firebase at the project but not for this methoed,and i try with JS API with google web service API key and its work,i cannot use android API Key for JS

Answer (score 0):

From your console we can see that the `MyProfileActivity` activity is making constant calls to `Relayout`.
These calls are very heavy on the phone.
When an app reaches a limit of memory on the phone the Operating System automatically crashes the app.
This is why your app keeps crashing.
Also please keep in mind that the behavior may be phone dependent. Although faulty code will jam up the the thread(s), but if you are using a phone with higher specs then the app might just lag and be frozen or unresponsive, whereas on a phone with lower specs the app would just crash.

To fix this, check `MyProfileActivity` for any listeners which for whatever reason are constantly being called.
A possible cause is that you have code that requests for location permission which is called within a Google Maps listener.
Hint: check the `onResume()` listener. If you have a permission checker which constantly asks for permission, and you have to click 'Don't ask again' and Deny the permission, it will constantly make the calls to the Operating System to request for permission.

On the phone, go to `Settings -> Apps`. Select your app from the list. Scroll down to the `App Settings` section and click `Permissions`. Enable all permissions on the app. Then, try running your app. If your app does not crash, then you will have found that the cause of your problem was the constant hidden calls requesting permissions from the Operating System.

The permanent fix is to move the call for permission request or whatever else is being called from a listener which is called all the time such as `onResume` to somewhere it is called less often or just once, such as `onMapReady`. The elegant solution is to remember the user's preference instead of asking them every time they load the map, so if they wanted to enable location permissions they would have to do so from the Settings app of their phone, or even from a Settings menu within the app.